# How to open cash drawer connected to local computer using POS for .Net in remote session

Tags: opos, pos-for-.net

I'm trying to open cash drawer that is connected to my local computer from terminal server session (remote desktop) using POS for .Net. 
Cash drawer is USB - connected directly to my computer and supports OPOS.
I'm able to open it if I install OPOS driver on terminal server and register device.
Is there a way to skip this step with device installation/registration on terminal server? I'm trying to make generic solution for all OPOS supported cashdrawers that can be attached to the system.

Answer (score 0):

There is a mechanism called WS-POS, which is supposed to support the operation you want.
[ABOUT THE WEB SERVICES FOR POINT OF SALE SPECIFICATION VERSION 1.3.1](https://www.omg.org/spec/WS-POS/1.3.1/)

However, it adds middleware layer on POS for.NET and OPOS, and it installs it, so it takes more time to build the system.